# How to change login status in LoginView control

Tags: c#, asp.net, loginview, loginstatus

How to change status from first Template to second template when I'm login into the system?

```
<asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        [ <a href="~/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        Welcome!
        [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="/Logout.aspx"/> ]
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

How to detect login status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[take a look at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912276/asp-net-membership-how-to-set-the-user-as-logged-in)

Answer (score 1):

The LoginView Control handles this for you.  It is done using the ASP.NET Forms authentication and the "IsAuthenticated" property that is managed by ASP.NET.